# URL Redirect from Zip Code Form Entry

Tags: php, html, forms

I am completely stuck and would love some help. I tried to duplicate the code from a past similar question (located here: [URL Redirect from Zipcode Form Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087827)) and it isn't working.

I would like a simple one-line form a user can enter their zip code and it will automatically redirect them to a partner site. Ie. The user enters 80013 and it forwards them to www.domain1.com User enters 80303 and it forwards them to www.domain3.com

Form HTML:

```
<form method='GET' action='http://harvestmeat.com/regional-ads-by-zip-codes.php'>
  <div class="zipcode">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
    <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" />
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <input type='submit' name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
  </div>
</form>
```

regional-ads-by-zip-codes.php:

```
<?php
$zip = $_GET['zip'];

$loc1 = array (80013,80015,80007);
$loc2 = array (80601,80602,89509);
$loc3 = array (80303,80305);

if(in_array($zip, $loc1)) {
    header('Location: http://www.domain1.com');
} 
if(in_array($zip, $loc2)) {
    header('Location: http://www.domain2.com');
}
if(in_array($zip, $loc3)) {
    header('Location: http://www.domain3.com');
} 
else {
    header('Location: http://www.allelse.com');
}
```

Comment: and what's the problem here ?

Comment: So What is the problem ?

Comment: So what is not working? Are there errors? What is the current behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Redirect from Zipcode Form Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087827/url-redirect-from-zipcode-form-entry)

Comment: @LeoR.but actually... don't those look nearly identical?

Comment: use else if condition to get the output

Comment: the problem is you're allowing `http://www.allelse.com` to slip through as the last dealer, tighten up your if/elseif/else statements

Answer (score 0):

## Please check below code

```
<form method='GET' action='http://harvestmeat.com/regional-ads-by-zip-codes.php'>
  <div class="zipcode">
    <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
    <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" />
  </div>

  <div class="button">
    <input type='submit' name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
  </div>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['did_submit'])) {

    $zip = $_GET['zip'];

    $loc1 = array (80013,80015,80007);
    $loc2 = array (80601,80602,89509);
    $loc3 = array (80303,80305);

    if(in_array($zip, $loc1)) {
        header('Location: http://www.domain1.com');
    }else if(in_array($zip, $loc2)) {
        header('Location: http://www.domain2.com');
    }else if(in_array($zip, $loc3)) {
        header('Location: http://www.domain3.com');
    }else {
        header('Location: http://www.allelse.com');
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: That worked. I really appreciate the help.  I was completely stuck. THANK YOU!!